# convert NA values for some strings

Tags: pandas

How do I forward fill values if specific string is used for e.g. -"-

Here is my dataframe:

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

myst="""india / gujarat, 22905034 , 19:44   
india / kerala, -"-  , 19:33
-"-,  905154 ,   21:56

"""
u_cols=['country_state', 'index1', 'current_tm']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols, na_values=['-"-'])
```

I can correctly fill the country column but index1 values are not copied because of extra space.

```
df.ffill()
```

Replacing does not seem to work as well.

```
df.index1.replace('-"-' , '')
```

Is there any way to strip and then use the string as na_values parameter in read csv method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separator `\s*,\s*` so initial and ending spaces will be ignored, na_values would work fine

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep='\s*,\s*', names = u_cols, na_values=['-"-'],engine='python')

country_state      index1 current_tm
0  india / gujarat  22905034.0      19:44
1   india / kerala         NaN      19:33
2              NaN    905154.0      21:56
```

You can also import and then replace the na_values i.e

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols).replace('-"-', np.nan,regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me working:

```
df.index1 = df.index1.replace('\s*-"-\s*' , np.nan, regex=True)
```

But if want use `read_csv` then `converters` are necessary:

```
def conv(x):
    return np.nan if x.strip() == '-"-' else x.strip()

#define each column
convs={'index1': conv, 'current_tm': conv, 'country_state':conv}
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), converters=convs, names = u_cols)
print (df)
     country_state    index1 current_tm
0  india / gujarat  22905034      19:44
1   india / kerala       NaN      19:33
2              NaN    905154      21:56
```

Comment: Though I feel its a heavy duty we can use separator here